# What does an effect algebra mean in terms of familiar quantum concepts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I've heard of this particular representation of quantum theory before and been trying to toy with it for some time:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_algebra

but I am not quite sure how to directly interpret in terms of familiar concepts like probabilities, amplitudes and observables, given the terse description there. The article there is not entirely helpful in connecting clearly what an "effect" means in terms of observables, and it does not easily provide (e.g. I don't usually think of quantum operators as "bounded below the identity") an understanding of how to obtain that connection.

What, then, do the various terms in the effect algebra structure mean when it is used to describe a quantum system? From trying to massage it around some, I *believe* that the "effects" are supposed to be the same as at least elementary (yes/no, or 1/0) observables/questions, and the orthogonal relation $\perp$ means that it is possible to have simultaneous information about them, while $\oplus$ is like a logical OR, and $'$ is the logical NOT operation. And the OR is only possible for two questions $e$ and $f$ with $(e, f) \in {\perp}$ because it requires simultaneous information about both to be present to be evaluated.

Is this the correct understanding?

How then do we describe a state in this framework? It seems similar to the C*-algebra formalism, but perhaps more directly associatable to probabilities (this post was actually motivated by a recent question just posted here regarding the use of expected values in that formalism), so my guess is a state should be a function $p: E \rightarrow [0, 1]$, giving the probability any $e \in E$ has the answer "Yes", but am not sure how that the different values must relate. I'd presume that if for two questions $e$ and $f$ with $(e, f) \notin {\perp}$ then we must have that if $p(e)$ is $0$ or $1$ then $p(f)$ must be $\frac{1}{2}$ (i.e. maximal information about one gives no information about the other). Is this even remotely on track? If not, what is the correct formulation?